# ReactJS fetch call with AbortController

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, fetch

I am trying to cancel the fetch calls using the `AbortController`. This is what my API extraction looks like. I have a function that handles both get and post calls and these get and post methods and extracted out separately as well.

```
export async function customAjax(options){
   let options = {};
   options.headers = { ...options.headers, ...obj.headers };
   const response = await fetch(url, options);
   await response.json()
}

const get = (url, extra = {}) => api({ url, type: "GET", ...extra });
const post = (url, payload, extra = {}) => api({ url, data: payload ,type: "POST",
}, ...extra });

const api = async (payload) => {
      try {
          promise = customAjax(payload);
          const response = await promise;
          if (response && !errorMessage) {
            return { response, error: false, loading: false, request: promise };
          } else if (errorMessage) {
            return { response: false, error: "Error", loading: false, request: promise };
          }
      } 
     catch (e) {
         return { response: false, error: "Error", loading: false, request: promise };
     }
    return { response: false, error: false, loading: true, request: promise };
}
```

So from respective components, I will be calling get or post methods.

```
function MyComponent(){
  useEffect(() => {
    makeCall();
    saveResponse();
  }, []);

 async function makeCall(){
   const { response, error } = await post(URL, payload);
   // Handling code is not added here
 }

  async function saveResponse(){
   const { response, error } = await get(URL);
   // Handling code is not added here
  }
}
```

As you see this is a component where I call both the methods. I basically want to cancel the calls when moving away. What is ideal way to create a abort instance and pass it? How do I achieve with my current API structure. Some pointers would help and appreciated

Comment: It makes no sense to return the `promise` (as `.request`) from the `api()` after already having `await`ed it. Btw, `response` should be `null` not `false` in case of an error.

Comment: `return { response: false, error: false, loading: true, request: promise };` makes no sense. If you ever reach that line, it won't be still `loading`, instead if would have finished loading but with a falsy `response` (json value).

Comment: "*I basically want to cancel the calls when moving away.*" - have a look at the `useEffect` documentation for that.

Comment: @Bergi, This is just a overview of the code that is written, My question lies around, how to pass abort controller instance, when multiple calls are being made in the same component

Comment: Create the abort controller in the effect. Pass the abort signal to *each* api call. Abort it from the [effect cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup). Not much difference to cancelling a single call?

Comment: @Bergi, I want to use the same instance across all the fetch calls right, so writing in a single useeffect wont be right, correct me If I am wrong? Any other places I can create this instance ?

Comment: The `MyComponent` example you gave *has* only a single useeffect, that does all the calls. That's the place to create and use the single abort controller.

Comment: Would you know how to achieve this if you didn't share the instance between all the fetch calls? Can you [edit] your question to show the code of that? Might make it clearer to see where you're stuck.

Comment: @Bergi,Have not tried the approach. Just taking some pointers

Comment: Well I guess I gave enough pointers for you to try them out and find whether it's wrong or works as desired